# Azure ARM template : Setting parameter value using a variable

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to pass the environment parameter to a template and then to another template (line `webAppName: 'my-webapp-${{parameters.environment}}'`)

I get the error : `A template expression is not allowed in this context`.  Is it not possible to do that ?

### main pipeline (just the necessary code for clarity)

```
- stage: deploy
    displayName: 'Deploy Dev Stage'
    dependsOn: build
    condition: succeeded()
    jobs:
    - deployment: deploymentjob
      displayName: deployment job
      environment: dev  
      variables:         
        - template: variables/dev.yml
      strategy:
        runOnce:
   
          deploy:
            steps:
            - template: templates/pipeline-deploy/master.yml 
              parameters:              
                environment: 'dev'
```

### master.yml

```
parameters: 
  environment: ''

  steps:
    - template: webapp.yml
      parameters:
        webAppName: 'my-webapp-${{parameters.environment}}'
```

### then webapp.yml

```
parameters: 
   webAppName: ''

steps: 
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Deploy my app'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '(#some id)'
    WebAppName: ${{parameters.webAppName}}
    packageForLinux: '$(workFolder)/my-package.zip'
```

Comment: Hi Sam, it seems you've found the solution. Please consider adding it as answer and mark that so that more members with similar error message can benefit from that. Just reminder of [can I ...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: ok, done it just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the indentation in one of my YAML files, which was not correct. Adding an extra tab solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you're allowed to use variable substitution in ARM template parameters. But you ARE allowed to do so in variables.

So in master.yml, define a variables section, and compose your webAppName as a variable. Then pass that variable into webapp.yml instead of using a parameter.

Comment: thanks but actually that was not the problem. It was (as too often) a stupid indentation issue in my YAML... The script above works fine now.

Comment: ARM templates have given me a complex. I feel your pain.